# Bibulous or Biblatex with Footnote Referencing

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a rather complicated set of referencing requirements for my thesis.  I have references in a variety of languages (Russian, Japanese, Chinese), where the transliteration of author names, translation of titles etc. needs to be placed alongside the original.  I need to use footnote referencing, where the first use of the reference shows the full reference in the footnote and following uses on the same page show Ibid. A shorter reference is used for the first use on subsequent pages.  I also want to customise the ordering of names:

Western - Last Name, First Name order in the final reference list; First Name, Last Name order in footnotes.

Oriental - Last Name, First Name order in both the final reference list and the footnotes.

I have set up an extra field in the `.bib` file specifying which entries are western and which entries are oriental (field name is `oriental`).

The style `verbose-inote` within `biblatex` can get me part of the way there, but I am going to have to make modifications.  I have recently discovered Bibulous, which looks very attractive as it enables me to specify exactly how I want things to work quite easily.  Can Bibulous be used to produce footnote referencing like that provided by `verbose-inote`?  If so, is it possible to specify different styles for the footnote referencing and the final reference list?

Although I would love to see a Bibulous solution, it is probably going to be easier to modify a `biblatex` solution than to try and implement footnote referencing in Bibulous if it doesn't already exist.  I am using XeLaTeX.  The name (author/editor) issue is the problem - titles and publishers work fine as is.  Sample .bib references are:

```
@Book{Sofronov:Grammar,
title = {{Grammar of the Tangut Language, 2 volumes }{\russian Грамматика Тангутского Языка}},
author = {\noopsort{Sofronov}Sofronov, {\russian М.В. Софронов}, M.V.},
publisher = {Scientific Publishing House {\russian Издательство ``наука''}},
address = {Moscow},
year = {1968}
}

@Book{LiFanwen:1997,
editor = {\noopsort{Li}Li, {\chinese 李范文}, Fanwen},
title = {Tangut-Chinese Dictionary {\chinese 夏漢字典}},
publisher = {China Social Science Press {\chinese 中国社会科学出版社}},
address = {Beijing, China},
year = 1997,
oriental = 1
}
```

I am planning on using the oriental field to determine how first/last names are ordered.

At the moment I have the author's original name appearing as the middle entry in a three-element name, so I can access it using `#7`.

I read somewhere that I need to map the oriental field to one of the pre-existing field names, which I am doing at the top of my `.tex` file:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-inote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{xixia.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldset=oriental, fieldvalue=0]
      \step[fieldsource=oriental]
      \step[fieldset=usera, origfieldval, append]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\russian{Times New Roman}
\newfontface\chinese{AR PL UMing CN}
```

Not sure what to do from here.  I have been playing with adding `\DeclareNameFormat` in `verbose-inote.cbx` - something like below (this code doesn't work):

```
\DeclareNameFormat{author-with-orig}{%
  \ifnumcomp{\thefield{usera}}{=}{1}
    {#1%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\addcomma\space #3 \space #7}}
    {\ifblank{#3}{}{#3\space}%
     #1 \space #7}%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}
    {}}
```

and then modifying the following two entries in `verbose-inote.cbx` to refer to `author-with-orig`:

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{author-with-orig}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}

\newbibmacro*{footcite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{author-with-orig}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}
```

A MWE is as follows (in the interests of simplicity, I have left out foreign language titles, publishers, etc. as they work fine):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\russian{Times New Roman}
\newfontface\chinese{AR PL UMing CN}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{xixia.bib}
@Book{NonOrientalBook,
title = {Non-Oriental Book},
author = {NonOrientalLast, {\russian Имя}, NonOrientalFirst},
publisher = {Non-Oriental Book Publisher},
address = {Moscow},
year = 1968
}

@Book{OrientalBook,
editor = {OrientalLast, {\chinese 名字}, OrientalFirst},
title = {Oriental Book},
publisher = {Oriental Book Publisher},
address = {Beijing},
year = 1997,
oriental = 1
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-inote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{xixia.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
        \step[fieldset=oriental, fieldvalue=0]
        \step[fieldsource=oriental]
        \step[fieldset=usera, origfieldval, append]
    }
  }
}


\begin{document}
A book by a non-oriental author\footcite{NonOrientalBook}.  A document by an oriental author\footcite{OrientalBook}.

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The footnotes should then be:

```
1. NonOrientalFirst NonOrientalLast Имя ... (title, publisher, etc.)
2. OrientalLast OrientalFirst 名字 ...
```

The bibliography should contain:

```
NonOrientalLast NonOrientalFirst Имя ...
OrientalLast OrientalFirst 名字 ...
```

Comment: If you are interested in a bibulous solution you should probably drop the specific `biblatex` tag. If you are interested in a `biblatex` solution a short example `.bib` entry of how you plan to make western and oriental names known would be appreciated. What are you missing from `verbose-inote` except for the name handling?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't managed to use the oriental field that I was planning on using (I can't work out how to access this information within `\DeclareNameFormat` code), but I have managed to come up with a solution by prepending a code `XXXORI` to the surname of the oriental authors and using the `xstring` package.  I have also added extra authors to the code below to test how multiple authors work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\russian{Times New Roman}
\newfontface\chinese{AR PL UMing CN}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{intcalc}

\begin{filecontents*}{xixia.bib}
@Book{NonOrientalBook,
title = {Non-Oriental Book},
author = {NonOrientalLast, {\russian Имя}, NonOrientalFirst and NonOrientalLast2, {\russian Имя2}, NonOrientalFirst2},
publisher = {Non-Oriental Book Publisher},
address = {Moscow},
year = 1968
}

@Book{OrientalBook,
editor = {XXXORIOrientalLast, {\chinese 名字}, OrientalFirst and XXXORIOrientalLast2, {\chinese 名字2}, OrientalFirst2 and XXXORIOrientalLast3, {\chinese 名字3}, OrientalFirst3},
title = {Oriental Book},
publisher = {Oriental Book Publisher},
address = {Beijing},
year = 1997
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=verbose-inote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{xixia.bib}

\DeclareNameFormat{author-with-orig}{%
  \IfSubStr{#1}{XXXORI}
    {\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{6}\space#3#7}
    {#3\space#1#7}
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\intcalcDec{\value{liststop}}}
    {and\space}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
      {\addcomma\space}
      {}}}

\DeclareNameFormat{sortname}{%
  \IfSubStr{#1}{XXXORI}
    {\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{6}\space#3#7}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=1}
      {#1\addcomma\space#3#7}
      {#3\space#1#7}}
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}=\intcalcDec{\value{liststop}}}
    {and\space}
    {\ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
      {\addcomma\space}
      {}}}

\renewbibmacro*{footcite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{author-with-orig}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}


\begin{document}
A book by a non-oriental author\footcite{NonOrientalBook}.  A document by an oriental author\footcite{OrientalBook}.

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```